# What do I use to put both CSS menu's side by side?

Tags: html, css

I want this be on the bottom of the page, but I forgot how to put them side by side, I know it's `float: left;` but I think I might be putting it in the wrong the location. So is there an easier way?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/76xsD/1/

Comment: Your question isn't clear yet. What, specifically, are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: I would like both css menu's to be put side by side in a horizontal formation such as this.

Comment: http://www.ssense.com Scroll down to the bottom.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You use two times the same id (#cssmenuuu) an id should be unique on a page. So use classes instead. Naming your id and classes is important and need to be descriptive.

Here is a fiddle with a working example

http://jsfiddle.net/NEyK2/1/

code explained:

```
<style type="text/css">
/*quick reset for margin and padidng*/
*{margin:0; padding:0}

/*makes sure the container does not collapse*/
.container{
    overflow:hidden;
}

/*float the get the elment next to each other*/
.menu{
    width:125px;
    background:black;
    padding:10px 4px;
    list-style:none;
    float:left;
    margin-left:10px;
}


.menu a{
    color:#fff;
    text-decoration: none;
}
</style>

<!-- container has overflow hidden so it does not collapse -->
<div class="container">
    <!-- no extra div is needed for the menu's -->
    <!-- both have the same class and are floated -->
    <ul class="menu">
        <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
    </ul>

    <ul class="menu">
        <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess you need item of menu side by side.
Here's the fiddle with menu items side by side.
http://jsfiddle.net/NEyK2/4/

Changed rik's code here

```
#cssmenuu ul li {
    display: block;
    float: left;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    background: #161616;
}
```

Added `float:left`

As @Rik pointed out you are using two ID's in a document.